# Visual Studio won't show my installed project templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying to install some custom made project templates for asp.net MVC4, however my Visual Studio 2012 Premium won't show the new templates. The templates are installed by a .VISX file like this one: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/hottowel-template

Visual Studio is showing this file as an "Enabled" and "Installed" Extension, but when I try to create a new ASP.NET MVC4 project it is not showing those templates as an option like shown in this image: [image: http://i3.asp.net/media/4007155/custom_mvc_templates_11.jpg?cdn_id=2013-03-08-003]

I'm just seeing the regular options and it is not showing me the Hot-Towel template or any other single page application template. Could you please tell me how to fix this if one of you guys knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by installing ASP.Net Web Tools Update Pack Fall 2012: 
http://www.asp.net/vnext

I decided to give the answer to my own question for helping others with the same question.

Comment: Hi Nick - I am up against the same problem, though installing those tools didn't seem to help (installed from the Web Platform updater). Was there anything else that needs to be done to get the template to show up? I am using VS2012.3. Thanks

Comment: No this was it for me, this update should fix it, have you tried updating it manually?